# regex select tags ending multiple buf after another tag

Tags: java, regex

Here is my text:

```
<img src="StackOverflow.jpg"><br>
<br><br><br><ba>
<img src="StackOverflow.jpg"><br><br>
<br>
<img src="StackOverflow.jpg"> <br><br> <br> 
<br>
```

I would like to select all `<br>` tags ending <s>(if space is between, I would like to select it too. But it is optional)</s> and after `>` and should not be at the beginning.

So expected selection should be:

1. first row - one`<br>`,
2. second row - not because `<br>` is not at the end
3. third row - yes, select two `<br>`
4. fourth row - no, because it begins
5. fifth row - no, is not after `>`
6. sixth row - no, it begins

What I've managed so far is:

```
(?<=>)(<br>*?$)
```

But regex selects only the last one. Is greedy selection is impossible after positive look back?

I was working on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)

Comment: Don't use regex for this. [Use a proper parser.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1)

Comment: In this case I need to use regex. I am aware of this action.

Comment: Thank You, but I need to use regex.

Comment: @deadfish What's the expected result?

Comment: What about [`"(?m)(?<=^|>)(?:[ \\t]*<br>)+[ \\t]*\\r?$"`](https://regex101.com/r/tN3rK1/2) Your demo input contains `<ba>` should that be `<br>` ?

Comment: `<ba>` is intended, is OK

Comment: Or without touching `<br>` if it's alone in line, drop `^|` from the lookbehind [like in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xL1aU1/1).

Comment: updated my question, thanks in advance.

Comment: @bobblebubble your answer should be marked as solved, can I ask you to post and explain this selection, please?

Comment: [Is it this demo, that works for you?](https://regex101.com/r/xL1aU1/1) But it does not fit your rule 5th row: NO Maybe it's as simple as [`(?m)(?<=>)(?:<br>)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/iL0xS4/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you don't parse XHTML with regex but this seems simple enough that it shouldn't matter;

If you would like to select all trailing `<br>` tags `( ?<br> ?)+$` should work ([example](http://regexr.com/3cs0k)).

If you would like to *delete* all trailing `<br>` tags but not lines consisting entirely of `<br>` replacing `(.)( ?<br> ?)+$` with `$1` should work ([example](http://regexr.com/3cs0n)).

If you would like to *select* all trailing `<br>` tags but not lines consisting entirely of `<br>` you'd probably need lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but here you go:

```
(<br>)+(<br>|\\s)*$
```

also possible:

```
(<br>)+(<br>|\\s){1,}$
```

was tested on notepad++

Comment: what do you mean will not work in java? this is regex, lol... what are you trying to do with all of those `<br>` tags?